# Problema con SharedPreferences

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un problema al utilizarlo ya que al escribirlo me aparece en letras de color rojo ademas de marcarme un error

SharedPreferences preferencias= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser facil, solo debes colocar el click encima de SharedPreferences y presionar Alt+Enter, luego seleccionar "**Import Static Method...**" o importar el metodo con el siguiente codigo:

```
import static androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences;
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Comment: lo intente pero no me aparece esa opción y de hecho ese import si lo tengo el que no me aparece es el de sharedpreferences

Comment: Aunque lo correcto al usar SharedPreferences es colocar:

`SharedPreferences preferencias = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
o
`SharedPreferences preferencias = getSharedPreferences("NOMBRE_PREFERENCIA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

en lugar del método `getDefaultSharedPreferences(...)`

Fuente: [https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences]

Comment: Has podido solucionar tu problema?